# Differential Equation Disease Modelling

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The rate at which people are infected per week after the outbreak of a disease is $${dP\over dt} = 0.8P \left(1 - {P\over 350}\right)$$ At the outbreak for the disease, $7$ people were infected. What is the initial condition problem for $P$?

I got everything to the left side with dP and left only 1 along with dt on the right. Then, using partial fractions, I got

∫${1\over 0.8P}$ + ${1\over 280(1-{P\over 350})}$

I integrated this further to get

${-5\over 4}$ln(350-P) + ${5\over 4}$ln(P)

I then did  ${ln(P)^{5/4}\over (350-P)^{5/4}}$ = t + c

I was unsure of what to do after this and how I can substitute the initial conditions (P as 7 and t as 0?, I'm not so sure).

Comment: Presumably $t$ is time in weeks, and $P$ is the number of people infected.  We are free to choose the starting time, but it's usual to take that as $t=0$, so the initial condition would be $P(0) = 7$.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. So do I substitute 7 and 0 into the equation to get c and then this would be the final equation?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your last formula is not correct.

You correctly wrote
$$\frac{5 }{4}\log (P)-\frac{5}{4} \log (350-P)=t+c$$ which rewrite
$$\frac{5 }{4}\log \left(\frac{P}{350-P}\right)=t+c_1\implies \log \left(\frac{P}{350-P}\right)=\frac{4 }{5}t+c_2$$ Now, exponentiate both sides
$$\frac{P}{350-P}= \exp\left(\frac{4 }{5}t+c_2 \right)=c_3\exp\left(\frac{4 }{5}t \right)$$ Now, solve for $P$
$$P=\frac{350\, c_3\, e^{4 t/5}}{1+c_3\, e^{4 t/5}}$$ Now, use the condition
$$7=\frac{350\, c_3}{1+c_3}\implies c_3=\frac 1{49}\implies P=\frac{350 \,e^{4 t/5}}{49+e^{4 t/5}}$$

Comment: Oh yes, thank you!